# Does MonetDB support tables > 70k columns

Tags: r, rdbms, monetdb

**Does MonetDB support tables with ~74,000 columns?**

**Number of Columns:** 
74,000 columns. Yes I am asking about a table with seventy-four-thousand columns.

**Data types:** 
All data types for columns in these tables would be a mix of 50% of columns Int, 40% of columns Decimal(10,2), and 10% of columns  Varchar(255).

**Number of Rows / Records:** 
Each table would contain 300,000 to 750,000,000 rows

**Context of Project:**

> - This is not for a data warehouse use case.
>
>   - This is a data science project with high dimensions and no duplicate data so there's no way to build a different data model, e.g.
>       Star Schema, etc. is not an option for this project.
>   - My use case is reading from and inserting into these tables. No updates. No deletes. I will analyze data in these tables using R
>       natively in MonetDB so I can keep all data in MonetDB rather than
>       transfer to R, analyze and insert results from R back into MonetDB,
>       etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 74K columns should be fine.

But: If you have 750M rows in such a table (55 trillion fields), for four-byte-integers, the table will occupy ~ 200 TB of disk space (!). Its unlikely you have that much...